# case class context in specs2 acceptance tests: "must is not a member of Int"

Tags: scala, bdd, specs2

I'm using specs2 (v1.8.2) on with Scala (v2.9.1) to write acceptance tests. Following the example at http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.SpecStructure.html#Contexts, I have the following Specification and context case class:

```
import org.specs2._


class testspec extends SpecificationWithJUnit { def is =

    "test should" ^
        "run a test in a context" ! context().e1

}

case class context() {

    def e1 = 1 must beEqualTo(1)
}
```

I get a compiler error:

> error: value must is not a member of Int def e1 = 1 must beEqualTo(1)

when compiling the context case class.

Obviously I'm new to specs2 (and to Scala). References to the appropriate documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the doc is wrong (*was* wrong, I fixed it now).

The correct way to write declare the case class for a context is usually to include it in the `Specification` scope:

```
import org.specs2._

class ContextSpec extends Specification { def is =
  "this is the first example" ! context().e1

  case class context() {
    def e1 = List(1,2,3) must have size(3)
  }
}
```

Otherwise if you want to reuse the context in another specification, you can, as Dario wrote, access the `MustMatchers` functionalities either by importing the `MustMatchers` object methods or by inheriting the `MustMatchers` trait.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. And awesome project, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

must is not a member of Int, because to "must" is not known in the context of your "context" class. Put the method "e1" inside your specification class and it should work. E.g.

```
import org.specs2._

class TestSpec extends Specification { def is =
  "test should" ^
    "run a test in a context" ! e1 ^
    end

  def e1 = 1 must beEqualTo(1)

}
```

#### edit

Ah, I see what you want ;-). This should work like this:

To have the matchers in the scope of the context class you have to import the MustMatchers.

```
import org.specs2._
import matcher.MustMatchers._

class ContextSpec extends Specification { def is =
  "this is the first example" ! context().e1
}

case class context() {
  def e1 = List(1,2,3) must have size(3)
}
```

Comment: But I want variable isolation and (Around/Outside/After/etc.) context support afforded by moving `e1` to a case class. This is copied from an example (using a case class) at the URL referenced in my question.